# how to save multiple input in one column in controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want save 3 input in 1 column in database

```
$register = $request->validate([
            'year' => 'required|numeric|min:1320|max:1398',
            'month' => 'required|numeric|min:1|max:12',
            'date' => 'required|numeric|min:1|max:31',]);

$user=user_information::where('user_id',$id)->first();
$user->birthday = $request->input('year');
$user->birthday = $request->input('month');
$user->birthday = $request->input('date');
```

or

```
$user->birthday = $request->input('year'.'-'.'month'.'-'.'date');
```

Comment: What kind of column is `birthday`? Is it a `DATE` or string col?

Comment: you want answer? i have solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concat the inputs.

```
$user->birthday = $request->input('date') . '-' . 
                  $request->input('month') . '-' . 
                  $request->input('year');
```

Comment: This depends on the type of the column. This won't work for a date column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Carbon` for this case:

```
$user->birthday = \Carbon\Carbon::create()->setDate(
    $request->input('year'),
    $request->input('month'),
    $request->input('day')
);
```

Just make sure that in the user model you cast `birthday` as a date:

```
protected $casts = [
    // other casts
    'birthday' => 'date',
];
```